# Sharepoint icon in titlebar

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

How can I add button icon in sharepoint site titlebar for connect to teams channel like in screenshot?

[image: sharepoint]

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is some OOTB solution for that. I think you would need to create a [spfx extension application customizer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/build-a-hello-world-extension#code-your-application-customizer) and in it add code to append your custom html to the app page header title.

Please be aware that this is rather unrecommended approach to use site html as api, but unfortunately I think this is the only solution for your requirement